# E: Unable to locate package libvirt-bin

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, apt

```
~$ sudo apt install libvirt-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libvirt-bin
```

Ubuntu 20.04

```
~$ apt --version
apt 2.0.2ubuntu0.1 (amd64)
```

Как поставить?

Comment: Пакет вроде переименовали в `libvirt-clients`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1089849/387795

Comment: @AlexeyTen `E: Unable to locate package libvirt-client`

Comment: @VictorVosMottor ну уж скопипастить-то можно без ошибок?

Comment: A! @AlexeyTen  got it ;)